# How do I know that my virtual guest is using VT-x?

Tags: kvm

I know my cpu supports VT-x, but how can I check that the KVM guest machine uses it? My Desktop is CentOS running a Windows 7 guest.

I'm asking because.. the virtual Windows 7 says I'm using a XEON CPU.. but in reality my Desktop has a corei5 CPU

**My question:** What is the KVM command for checking that a guest is using VT-x or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only place I've seen this info is in `virt-manager` and in the VM's XML file when you dump them.

*excerpt - Source: Wikipedia article on [x86 Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29)*

> Previously codenamed "Vanderpool", VT-x represents Intel's technology for virtualization on the x86 platform. On November 13, 2005, Intel released two models of Pentium 4 (Model 662 and 672) as the first Intel processors to support VT-x. The CPU flag for VT-x is "vmx"; in Linux, this may be checked via /proc/cpuinfo, or in Mac OS X via sysctl machdep.cpu.features.[19]

So the flag you're looking for is *vmx*.

#### CLI

*Example*

```
$ sudo virsh dumpxml visualstudio | grep -A 10 cpu
  <vcpu>2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='rhel5.4.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
```

So in the above output you're looking for a feature called *vmx*. If it's not present then it's disabled and/or not supported.

#### GUI

*Example*

[image: ss #1]

Pay special attention to your particular version of KVM/virsh since many of the features are only available/accessible in specific versions. See this guide for further details, titled: [Hypervisor features](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsFeatures).

**NOTE:** In the above output if a feature is denoted as off, then it isn't disabled, if it says on then it's enabled.

#### References

- [Domain XML format](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html)

Comment: So on the "CLI" I need to search for: "HMV", and on the GUI I need to search for the? - Thanks!

Comment: @evachristine - see updates